# Dax formula to find the last CHILD ID from PARENT ID in same table

Tags: powerbi, dax, parent-child, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

How can I get the last Child Id from Patent ID in Power BI

Project ID                Project Original ID
1234                      123
123

Comment: You should add a bit more information and desired output. Fix the table

Comment: |Plan |PROJ_ID |ORIG_PROJ_ID |Value|
|----------|-----------|--------------------|-------|
|Baseline |4632 |4631 |A
|Actual |4631 |         |B

this is the data I have...

and I need to get something like below

|PROJ_ID |Baseline Plan |Actual Plan|
|----------|----------------|------------|
|4631 |A                 |B               |

Answer (score 0):

you will left outer join 2 table from transform data -> home -> merge queries

u'll left outer parentId = ıd

[image]

[image]